# Can Twilio be used to answer a phone call and press a key?

Tags: automation, twilio, phone-call

I'm trying to find out if in general I can obtain a phone number from Twilio, then have another application dial that number and have twilio answer and press the # key or another sequence of keys. If this is possible I'd appreciate being pointed to any basic documentation to look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Good news, you absolutely can do that! You can buy a Twilio number. You then set a URL for that number, so that when Twilio receives a call on the number it will make a HTTP request to that number to find out what to do.

That URL will need to respond with [TwiML (which is XML)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to tell Twilio what to do with the call. To perform what you want to achieve, you need the [`<Play>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play).

In order to answer the call, press the # key and then hang up you would need to return this TwiML:

```
<Response>
  <Play digits="#"/>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

If you need to wait before pressing the key, you can use "w" to delay by 0.5s. So, to delay for 2 seconds then press the # you would need:

```
<Response>
  <Play digits="wwww#"/>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'm glad to know it can be done at least. Is there no way to accomplish this without having to run a web server on the internet that is accessible to Twilio to pull down those instructions? Does another service besides Twilio come to mind that might be able to accomplish this?

Comment: We do host what we call Twimlets, https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/12/twitch-week-tune-into-programming-tutorials-with-the-twilio-crew.html, which you could use to achieve this without your own server. You might need to look at the Echo twimlet as there's not one with your exact use case.

Comment: Just realised I posted entirely the wrong link there. Check out twimlets here: https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets